# Conic hull of the columns of a positive matrix

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, definition, convex-cone

The convex **conic hull** of the column space of an $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is defined as follows

$$\operatorname{ConHull}(\mathbf A) = \{ \mathbf A \mathbf x \mid \mathbf x \geq 0_n \}$$

By this definition, the conical hull of every positive (element-wise positive) matrix should be equal to the non-negative orthant of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, right?

It seems very obvious and trivial for me. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

- I use the definition of nonnegative orthant as $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | x \geq 0\}$.
- For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, $A[x]=xA$, for example $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1(3) \\ 2(3) \end{bmatrix} = 3\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$, then the conic hull of $A$ is equal to

$$\{ Ax| x \geq 0 , x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{ xA| x \geq 0 , x \in \mathbb{R}\} $$

$\{xA| x \geq 0 , x \in \mathbb{R}\} \neq $ non-negative orthant in $\mathbb{R}$. It is just a half-line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

- $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x \geq 0\} \neq \{ kA| k \geq 0 , k \in \mathbb{R}\} $
- To see that, the set on the left is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but the set on the right is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Edit: Another counter example:

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}$,

then the conic hull of $B$ is equal to

\begin{align}\left\{ y \left| y = B \begin{bmatrix} \lambda \\ \mu\end{bmatrix}, \lambda \ge 0, \mu \ge 0\right.\right\}&= \left\{ y \left| y =\begin{bmatrix} A & A \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda \\ \mu\end{bmatrix}, \lambda \ge 0, \mu \ge 0\right.\right\}  \\
&=  \left\{ y \left| y =\lambda A + \mu A, \lambda \ge 0, \mu \ge 0\right.\right\}  \\
&= \left\{ y \left| y =(\lambda + \mu )A, \lambda \ge 0, \mu \ge 0\right.\right\}  \\
&=\left\{ y \left| y =kA, k \ge 0, k \in \mathbb{R}\right.\right\}  \\\end{align}

which is not equal to the non-negative orthant in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is just a half-line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

- $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \geq 0\} \neq \{ kA| k \geq 0 , k \in \mathbb{R}\} $
- The set on the left is a quadrant but the set on the right is just a half line.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that x is a vector not a scalar

Comment: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^1$. so the counter example still works right?

Comment: in that case non-negative orthant is just the half line, right ?

Comment: what is your definition of non-negative orthant?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant  in 1d orthant is the ray (half line)

Comment: Is $(-\infty, 0]$ the non-negative octant since it is a ray(half line)?

Comment: how come you consider ray in the non positive region ?. I am talking as per the question assumptions (positivity of x and A )

Comment: because you just pointed out a property of nonnegative octant rather than the definition.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are saying.  How you define $kA$ ?.  I am talking about conic hull. So $Ax$ for all positive vectors $x$.

Comment: @Shew if the column space of $A$ isn't full dimensional, you will obtain an proper subcone.

Comment: more details are included to show the derivation of conic hull of $B$.

Comment: Ok. Now I got it.  If the matrix A has full column rank, then non-negative orthant = conic hull right ?

Comment: conic hull of $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$,  since you want it to be be the nonnegative orthant of $\mathbb{R}^n$, you will also need $m=n$.